# Trying to calculate the arithmetic median

Tags: python

I was just trying to calculate the arithmetic median of a list. Odd list length works but my program has problems with even list length.
here's an example:
[The example for the even numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djC0S.png)

Here is what I tried:

```
#the sorted list
number = int(input('How many numbers do you want to put in? '))

print("")

values = []
for i in range(number):
    values.append(int(input('Please enter a value: ')))

print("")
sort = sorted(values)
print("Sorted list:", sort)


#the function
firstMid = int(len(sort)) / 2
secoundMid = (int(len(sort)) / 2) + 1

if isOdd(len(values)) == True:
    print("Zentralwert:", values[int(len(sort)/2)]) #odd numbers
else:

    print("Zentralwert:", (firstMid + secoundMid) / 2)
```

Comment: Are you finding mean or median?

Comment: You're confusing the length and **indices of the list midpoint**, with the actual **midpoint value** itself. `(firstMid + secoundMid) / 2` is wrong, you want `(sort[firstMid] + sort[secoundMid]) / 2`. A tip to avoid this sort of gotcha is always give indices a name that makes it obvious they're indices not values, so instead of `firstMid, secondMid` I'd call those `i_mid, i_mid+1`.

Comment: Also, `sort` is not a reserved word in base python (it is a method of a list, though: `list.sort()`), but it's still confusing to use `sort` as the name for the sorted values list. I'd call that `values_s` or something.

Comment: Also, `len()` will always return an integer, so `int(len(sort))` is totally unnecessary, just use `len(sort)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to find median.

For odd numbers, it's the middle number.
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] -> Median is 5 at index 4 means index = len(arr) // 2 `# //  is integer division in python and returns floor value. So 9/2 = 4.5 but 9//2 = 4`

Now for even numbers, median would be mean of middle two numbers ie (4+5)/2.
Now here we need to target the correct elements using correct index.
For 8 elements, the correct number would be at index len(arr)//2 `8//2 = 4` and len(arr)//2 - 1 `8//2 -1 = 4-1=3`

Your code should now be this.

```
#the function
firstMidIndex = int(len(sort)) // 2
secoundMidIndex = (int(len(sort)) // 2) - 1

if isOdd(len(values)) == True:
    print("Zentralwert:", sort[firstMidIndex] #odd numbers
else:

    print("Zentralwert:", (sort[firstMidIndex] + sort[secoundMidIndex]) / 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want,

```
#the sorted list
number = int(input('How many numbers do you want to put in? '))

print("")

values = []
for i in range(number):
    values.append(int(input('Please enter a value: ')))

print("")
sort = sorted(values)
print("Sorted list:", sort)


#the function
firstMid = int(len(sort)) / 2
secoundMid = (int(len(sort)) / 2) + 1

if isOdd(len(values)) == True:
    print("Zentralwert:", sort[int(len(sort)/2)]) #odd numbers
else:

    print("Zentralwert:", (sort[firstMid] + sort[secoundMid]) / 2)
```

Comment: it does not work:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\lukas\Visual Studio Code Projects\sorting numbers\main.py", line 56, in <module>
    print("Zentralwert:", (sort[firstMid] + sort[secoundMid]) / 2)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Comment: check the answer of @gsb22 that one seems correct to me.

Comment: `len(sort)/2` will give a float.5 when the length is odd, you want `//2` instead (integer division).